# How to add autocomplete to search input text with angularjs and remote database?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wrote a search engine that works with a remote db server and draws records from it.
I want to add AUTO COMPLETE to INPUT.
I tried using the Angularjs tool (mark on code) and for some reason it didn't work for me.
Can anyone tell me why?
if there is a simpler approach to coding this feature I would love to hear too

JS

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", ['ngRoute']);

myapp.controller("homeController", ['$scope', '$http',function ($scope, $http) {   

//new section:////
$scope.query = function (searchText) {
            return $http
                .get('http://localhost:59836/api/Jobs/searchjobs/' + searchText)
                .then(function (data) {

                    return data;
                });
        };
    ////

    $scope.search = function (inSearch) {
        $scope.inSearch = inSearch;
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:59836/api/Jobs/searchjobs/" + $scope.inSearch

        }).then(function Success(response) {

            $scope.jobs = JSON.parse(response.data);       

        }, function Error(response) {
                alert(response.statusText);
        });

    };

}]);
```

html

```
<body>

    <div ng-controller="homeController">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                <div style="background-color:#1d1a1a; padding:4%;" class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Job title or keywords" ng-model="inSearch" />
///////new section:///////////
                    <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="inSearch" md-items="item in query(inSearch)">
                        <md-item-template>
                            <span md-highlight-text="inSearch">{{item}}</span>
                        </md-item-template>
                    </md-autocomplete>
//////////////////////////////////////
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="search(inSearch)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                                <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div ng-repeat="job in jobs">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        <h2 style="color:dodgerblue">{{job.JobTitleText}}</h2>
                        <h4>{{job.job_description}}</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Formed the title as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple typeahead instead of using directive, got through the code below :

***HTML Code:***

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Job Title / Keywords"
            uib-typeahead="job.JobTitleText as job.JobTitleText for jobs in searchJob($viewValue)"
            typeahead-on-select="setJob($item)"
            typeahead-editable="false"
            typeahead-loading="loadingJobs" 
            typeahead-no-results="noJobsFound"
            ng-model="inSearch" required=""/>
<div>
    <p ng-show="noJobsFound">No JobsFound</p>
    <p ng-show="loadingJobs">Loading...</p>
</div>
```

***Angular Code:***

```
$scope.setJob = function (job) {
//If your http response return object then write 'job.JobTitleText' or if it returns simple string then you write 'job'
    $scope.inSearch = job.job.JobTitleText; //This is considering response is object
};
$scope.searchJob = function (searchTerm) {
    return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:59836/api/Jobs/searchjobs/" + searchTerm

        }).then(function Success(response) {

            $scope.jobs = JSON.parse(response.data);       

        }, function Error(response) {
                alert(response.statusText);
        }).$promise;
};
```

That's it, this will solve your problem. Just a small suggestion which I want to give you which I am sure you must have thought is that build your back end query in such a way that your database returns the suggestions like in MySql we have query like this :

Consider you have a table by name employee where you want to put a typeahead on employee name and you have a field called 'name' in your table where you are storing employees name, so your query will be

```
SELECT * from employee WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%a%';
```

This query will return all the employees whose name has 'a' letter in them, So I hope your $scope.searchJob() function also returns data in this way.

Give this a try, I hope this solves your problem.